# HTTP Status 406 - Not Acceptable angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that this question is repeated but I search for solution in angular framework and I didn't find so what I do easily I send post request by `$http.post` angular object but the answer is `HTTP Status 406 - Not Acceptable` .
The answer actually is a url link so I must configure server endpoint to produce 'text/plain' what is the wrong ? This is my code

```
$scope.sendOrder = function (orderObject) {
       // use $.param jQuery function to serialize data from JSON
        var baseUrl = platformOrigin + "/shopintegration/ws/" + PlatformService.user.getName() + "/subscription/order";
        var config = {
            headers : {
               'Accept': 'text/plain'
            }
        };
        $http.post(baseUrl, orderObject, config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.PostDataResponse = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                "<hr />status: " + status +
                "<hr />headers: " + header +
                "<hr />config: " + config;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the error from either the console or the network tab.

Comment: A 406 error means that the server is attempting to send a content type that isn't listed in the Accept header.   Have you confirmed that the server is in fact sending "text/plain" and not some other content type?  And is there a reason you're explicitly overriding the default Accept header here?

Comment: in the web service founded @produses(text/plain) but i dont know why it is not working